# Inaccurate result when mul'ing

Tags: assembly, x86, factorial, multiplication

so I have some weird results when trying to mull a 32bit by a 32bit.

```
 mov eax, [bignum]  
 call writedec
 call crlf

 mul ebx                ;EDX:EAX = EAX*EBX
 mov [bignum], eax  ;save result
 call writedec
 call crlf

 mov eax, edx
 call writedec
 call crlf
 mov ecx, edx           ;save carried part in ECX
```

this prints out:

```
479001600

1932053504

1
```

When the ebx is 13.

How could this possibly happen? I am lost.

Comment: What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Results ... ? Because of writedec calls and ebx you can see what's wrong yourself

Comment: No, I cannot. Those are the results I would expect.

Comment: Okay, 479001600*13 is 6227020800, first line is correct later ones are not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

479001600*13=6227020800, or, 0x17328CC00 in hex.  This is too big for 32bits.

1*0x100000000=0x100000000

0x17328CC00-0x100000000=0x7328CC00, or 1932053504 in decimal.

So, no news here.

Put another way, your results are 1 in EDX and 1932053504 in EAX.

EDX contains the higher-order 32 bits of the result, so multiply by 2^32, ie. 0x100000000:

1 * 0x100000000 = 0x100000000

EDX contains the lower-order 32 bits of the result:

0x7328CC00

Add them together to get all 64 bits of result:

0x100000000 + 0x7328CC00 = 0x17328CC00

0x17328CC00 in decimal is 6227020800  QED.

Comment: Yes, that is too big for 32 bits, but mul stores results in 64 bits - 32 bit of edx and 32 bits of eax, so why wouldn't it work? How else can I implement multiplying bigger numbers if not like that?

Comment: It does work!  EDX is 1 - correct. EAX is 1932053504 - also correct.

Comment: Oops!  Slipped a zero on the 100000000's.  Edited it in.

Comment: How can I get  6227020800 from it then?

Comment: 6227020800 in what representation?  ATM, you have the correct value in binary, divided between two 32-bit registers.  Do you want to write the value in decimal to your output stream?  If so, you will need another version of writedec that can handle a 64-bit binary in two registers.   Not sure what you want?

Comment: Yes, in decimal. I finally understand why it works the way it works, but I am afraid I won't be able to get it to work, lol. Basically my program is an factorial function on 128 bit numbers, so in the end I'd have to write a writedec function that handles 128bit binary in 4 registers and I don't know how to do that.